# How to pick color from image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, artificial-intelligence, color-picker

I am trying to get color from image in Flutter.

I'm trying [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_color_picker) but it's not working.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator

Comment: Thanks I will achieve this by Using Palette generator

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the [paletter_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator) package

```
 var paletteGenerator;
    var itemBackgroundColor;

    Future<PaletteGenerator> _updatePaletteGenerator() async {
      paletteGenerator = await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
        Image.asset(product.image).image,
      );
      return paletteGenerator;
    }

//Then return a Future Builder

 return FutureBuilder<PaletteGenerator>(
      future: _updatePaletteGenerator(), // async work
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PaletteGenerator> snapshot) {
  itemBackgroundColor = snapshot.data.dominantColor.color;
   },
 );
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks

Comment: You can mark my answer as the right answer, since it helped you